# Python Pandas - vectorize custom function instead of apply

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas DataFrame with a city name and a date as follows :

```
In[34]: df.head(6)
Out[34]: 
       CITY        DATE
0    LONDON  2017-03-12
1    LONDON  2017-03-12
2     PARIS  2014-05-05
3     PARIS  2017-03-12
4    LONDON  2017-03-12
5  NEW-YORK  2017-03-12
```

I also have another DataFrame matching a person to city for a given time range (it basically says this person was in this city between START date and END date)

```
In[51]: db.head()
Out[51]: 
       CITY PERSON       START         END
0     PARIS    ID4  2014-01-01  2017-03-16
1  NEW-YORK    ID5  2014-01-07  2016-12-31
2    LONDON    ID1  2014-01-01  2016-05-08
3  MONTREAL    ID1  2016-05-09  2017-03-16
4     TOKYO    ID5  2017-01-01  2017-03-16
```

I would like to to add a column to `df` to determine for each row which was the person in the given city for the given date .

I was able to achieve it using a custom function `myfunc` that I apply row-wise to `df` using `df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['CITY'], x['DATE']), axis=1)`.

`myfunc` simply identifies in `db` the correct `PERSON` as follows:

```
def myfunc(city, date):
    return db.loc[(db.CITY==city) & (db.START <= date) & (db.END >= date), 'PERSON'].values[0]
```

This works well but it is rather slow for very large dataframes... I was trying to somehow merge the `db` data into `df` or at least to implement a vectorized version of what I did without relying on a row-wise implementation. 
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

- `df` must be sorted by `'DATE'`
- `db` must be sorted by `'START'` then by `'END'`
- we use the `by` parameter to only match up by `'CITY'`
- `query` at the end to make sure we only get `'END' >= 'DATE'`

---

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df.sort_values('DATE'),
    db.sort_values(['START', 'END']),
    left_on='DATE', right_on='START', by='CITY'
).query('DATE <= END')

    CITY       DATE PERSON      START        END
0  PARIS 2014-05-05    ID4 2014-01-01 2017-03-16
3  PARIS 2017-03-12    ID4 2014-01-01 2017-03-16
```

Notice that only the `'PARIS'` entries have matched with the data you provided.